# stationary distribution equation

Tags: probability, systems-of-equations, markov-chains

I have a question to solve a stationary distribution equation for a DMC. My equations look like this

$$\pi_0 = (1-p)\pi_1$$
$$\pi_1 = \pi_0 + (1-p)\pi_2$$
$$\pi_i = (1-p)\pi_{i+1} + p\pi_{i-1}, 2\le i\le n-1$$
$$\pi_n = \pi_n+p\pi_{n-1}$$

for $0<p<1$. I know as well $\sum \pi_i = 1$. But how can I solve such a system? I've tried to write down some cases but can't see a particular form for a generalization.

Comment: (a) What do you mean by $\pi_n = \pi_n$? (b) hint: write down the recursion as $\pi_{i+1}=F(\pi_{i},\pi_{i-1})$

Comment: @user619894 well it means that once we are in $n$ we stay there, i.e. the state $n$ is absorbing

Comment: @user619894 I have $\pi_{i+1} = \frac{\pi_i-p\pi_{i-1}}{1-p}$, but would that help?

Comment: Yes, it is a linear recursion. Do you know how to solve them?

Comment: @user619894 is it corrcet, that the solutions to the characteristic equation are $-1, \frac{p}{p-1}$?

Comment: I get a different result. Check the signs.

Comment: @user619894, yes sorry, it should be $1, \frac{p}{1-p}$, agree?

Comment: The equation seems not to be correct, note that from its recursion we can obtain the transition matrix, but if we sum the elements of the last row that sum does not give 1, which is incorrect. So that there are no problems, you should change the last equation to $\pi_{n}=p(\pi_{n-1}+\pi_{n})$

Comment: @DiegoFonseca you are absolutely right! I've edited my question. thanks for pointing out

Comment: @swissy With your modification, the problem still persists.

Comment: @DiegoFonseca the transition probabilities are given by $p_{0,1}=1, p_{i,i+1}=p, p_{i,i-1}=1-p,1\le i\le n-1$ and $p_{n,n}=1$ for a $0<p<1$. Aren't my equations correct?

Comment: @swissy According to your transition matrix, we have that the correct equations are:
$$\pi_{0}=(1-p)\pi_{1}$$
$$\pi_1 = \pi_0 + (1-p)\pi_2$$
$$\pi_i = (1-p)\pi_{i+1} + p\pi_{i-1}, 2\le i\le \color{red}{n-2}$$
$$\color{red}{\pi_{n-1}=p\pi_{n-2}}$$
$$\pi_{n}=p\pi_{n-1}+\pi_{n}.$$

Comment: your last equation implies $\pi_{n-1},\pi_{n-2}=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

There has been some confusion in the comments regarding the boundary conditions at $n$, so I want to clarify what I think is going on here:
The relations should be viewed as $\pi_i = F_i(\pi_{i-1},\pi_{i-2}) $ that is, each $\pi_i$ is determined as a function of the two lower $\pi$'s. When the equations are written in that way, we see that the value of $\pi_0$ determines the entire solution. Writing relationships as $\pi_i = G_{i}(\pi_{i+1},\pi_{i-1}) $ is confusing and leads to various contradictions when we try to write both an equation for $\pi_{n-1}$ **and** $\pi_{n}$.

**Bottom line**: having both special conditions for $i=0$ and $i=n$ *and* normalization causes the equations to become over determined ( to make an analogy to a second order ode with 2 boundary conditions *and* a normalization condition). The $\pi_n$ equation is spurious in my opinion.

**END OF EDIT**

Start from the recursion for $2\le i \le n-1$:
$$(1-p)\pi_{i+1}-\pi_i +p\pi_{i-1}=0$$ and consider solutions of type $a\lambda^{i}$, solve the quadratic equation to get $\lambda_{+},\lambda_{-}$.

Consider the general solution
$$ \pi_i = a\lambda_{+}^{i}+b\lambda_{-}^{i}$$
and set $a,b$ by using the normalization and the boundary conditions.

Comment: i have some trouble to find the constants. I tried the following, since $p_{n,n}=1$ we should have $1=a+b(\frac{p}{1-p})^N$ and as they need to sum up to one, $\sum_ia + b(\frac{p}{1-p})^i = 1$. Is that correct? I get a very ugly expression if I plug $a = 1-b(\frac{p}{1-p})^N$ into the second equation

Comment: what is $p_{n,n}$?

Comment: it means if I hit state $n$, I will stay there for sure, I think it translates into $\pi_n = 1$

Comment: If it stays there for sure, then the steady state is 1 at n and 0 elsewhere

Comment: I updated my question as there was a mistake for the last update, i.e. $\pi_n = pi_n +p\pi_{n-1}$

Comment: @swissy, is my answer clear after your correction?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as this would imply $\pi_{n-1}= 0$ and hence $p_i = 0$ for all $i<N$. so we have $\pi_n = 1$ and the rest zero? Is this because the state $n$ is absorbing?

Comment: The equation $\pi_n=\pi_n+p\pi_{n-1}$ indeed doesn't really make sense. Are you sure of it? Note that this is not what @Diego Fonseca proposed.

Comment: with the corrected equations I get that $a=-b(\frac{p}{1-p})^{N-2}$, but what is my second equation I can use this for? I see that now all the $\pi_i=0$ for $i<N$, hence $\pi_N=1$, but is there a way to prove this using the form we derived above via the characteristic equation?